# Get Each Element Of Array Value

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an Hashmap

```java
 private Map<String, int[]> aMap = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
```

Where I put multiple values inside of it

```java
 aMap.put("3", new int[]{7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 57, 64, 71, 78, 85});
 aMap.put("5", new int[]{20, 39, 59, 79, 98, 118, 137, 157, 177, 196, 216, 236}) etc...
```

I need to reach every each element of array I used

```java
for (String key : aMap.keySet()) {
  System.out.println("key : " + key);
  System.out.println("value : " + Arrays.toString(aMap.get(key)));
}
```

I can see arrays with that However I would like to access all elements inside of each element
as an example
I  would like to get all these value separately 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 57, 64, 71, 78, 85
and compare them with a value which I already calculated (we can name it  as asValue).

Comment: Iterate the array with a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the map is `int[]` (an array of `int`), you can iterate through every array to get its field like this:

```
for (Entry<String, int[]> entry : aMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key : " + entry.getKey());
    for (int i : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println("  array element: " + i);
    }
}
```

Also the first for loop should be working with `Entry<String, int[]>` rather than just `Key`, as you won't have to do the table lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values of your map and store them in a local variable by something like

```
for (String key : aMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("key : " + key);
    int[] value = aMap.get(key);
    //do something with value array
}
```